# Is it possible to pause a Azure DocumentDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm converting a Azure DocumentDB to a Table Storage because of the high costs of DocumentDB.

I would like to pause / suspend the DocumentDB database for a while and not completely remove it. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not current way of pausing the service. Anyway, as almost all things in Azure, even when paused you would still be paying for it.

Comment: Thanks! Too bad, oh well I guess I just have to cross my fingers that all of my data is correct in my table storage db now..

Answer (score 5):

As gbellmann mentioned, there is no way to pause the service.

That being said; there are other workarounds. For example:

- Lower the throughput (RU/sec) to the minimum allowed for the collection.
- Use the [Data Migration Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46436) to export your data out of DocumentDB to JSON.
- Temporarily remove the DocumentDB collection. Re-create it once needed.
- Use the import tool to import the JSON back in to DocumentDB.

Here's a reference for using the Data Migration tool:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-import-data/

Comment: Thanks, yeah I found that tool and have saved the exported data in case I would need it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking away writes for the database for at least a short period of time.  Your data would be safe for comparisons but impossible for things to be written to it.  It would give you a safe status (even though you would still incur charges while in this hybrid state)

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-manage-account/

Regenerate the keys.

Comment: Thanks, but it's only a database I used for a small hobby project so for me it was enough to export the data.